# Pull Data for each Dow Jones 30 company with R

Tags: r

I am currently facing a problem regarding the pulling of data in R.
With the `getSymbols()` function I can already obtain data for each Dow Jones company.

For example, this gives me the data for apple from a chosen `start_date` until `end_date`:

```
getSymbols("AAPL", src = "yahoo", from = start_date, to = end_date
```

However I would somehow like to pull the data for all 30 companies. I dont want to do every company manually, so I was wondering if there is any way to pull the data all at once. So far I have not found any information regarding my problem.

I would be very thankfull for any help.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.  Replace `dow` with the appropriate vector.

```
library(quantmod)

dow <- c("AAPL", "BA", "CAT")
getSymbols(dow, dow.env <- new.env())

ls(dow.env)
# [1] "AAPL" "BA"   "CAT" 

head(dow.env$AAPL)
##            AAPL.Open AAPL.High AAPL.Low AAPL.Close AAPL.Volume AAPL.Adjusted
## 2007-01-03  12.32714  12.36857 11.70000   11.97143   309579900      10.41635
## 2007-01-04  12.00714  12.27857 11.97429   12.23714   211815100      10.64755
## 2007-01-05  12.25286  12.31428 12.05714   12.15000   208685400      10.57173
## 2007-01-08  12.28000  12.36143 12.18286   12.21000   199276700      10.62393
## 2007-01-09  12.35000  13.28286 12.16429   13.22429   837324600      11.50647
## 2007-01-10  13.53571  13.97143 13.35000   13.85714   738220000      12.05711

unlist(eapply(dow.env, nrow))
##  CAT AAPL   BA 
## 3250 3250 3250
```